# This jQuery page doesn't work, Why?

Tags: jquery

why doesn't this jQuery code work ? what is wrong ?

The expected behavior that it alerts out the content of the requested JSON file but it doesn't.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'http://api.xxxxxxxxx.com/0.1/cities/key=xxxx',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  crossDomain: true,
  success: function(data){
              $.each(data, function(i, el){
                    alert(el.city)
               });
         ;}
});
</script> 

<title>Example</title> 
</head> 
<body></body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe the request fails, so your `success` callback never gets called. Or maybe the response is invalid. Did you check your error console?

Comment: yes! it tells me that for more that half of the errors "function cf does not always return a value" - which is the very first line of the library file http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js - I know nothing about all of that :(

Comment: Try filtering warnings out of the console view, so you can focus on actual errors.

Comment: I filtered them on warning, all the errors from the lib file (at the second and third) line. I believe that the lib is okay since I loaded it from google directly. can't figure what the error is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resource that you are loading is not JSONP, it is just a JSON string, JSONP should look like this:

```
callback("jsonString");
```

Not all json can be loaded as jsonp, it has to be setup for it specifically.

[JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

Comment: @Fahd, Well you won't be able to load it cross domain as json, so that will only work if your creating this page on qaym.com.

Comment: well said. I will find out another solution to send an API request and handling the JSON file

Comment: could you check this question dear, the same problem + update (it supports jsonp) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891700/againupdated-this-jquery-code-doesnt-work-why

Answer (score 0):

function needs to have callback

```
callback({json:true});
```

and if you do not have control over target server, it's not possible to make jsonp request