# Again+Updated: This jQuery code doesn't work, Why?

Tags: jquery

I asked this morning a question about a jQuery code that's not working (which grabs a json file using API) then some great people told that I must have the json file in jsonp to use callback , which I wasn't have..

I communicated with the developer of the website that provides the API and he solved the problem so that it supports jsonp, but still the code doesn't work !!

here is the code of the page (you can see it viewing the source of this page http://rawaji.com/test.html )

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
                    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://api.qaym.com/0.1/countries/key=u2gTerCTZDudTCMhQBQ9&jsoncallback=?",
        function(data){
          $.each(data, function(i,item){
             $("#results").append("<span class='result' >" + item.name + "</span></br>");
            if ( i == 3 ) return false;
          });
        });
  });
  </script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="results">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

just a little note, that FireBug tells me no errors in the code and even the console tells that the file imported correctly (see the image here http://twitpic.com/5yycg5 )

WHAT IS MISSING !! :(

**UPDAATE**:

I used another consoler and it shows me this message!

> key=u2gTerCTZDudTCMhQBQ9&jsoncallback=jQuery16206894429267849773_1312140242381:-1
>   Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type
>   application/json.

I just know nothing about it, but I will search it. if someone has an idea, plz tell :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.qaym.com/0.1/countries/key=u2gTerCTZDudTCMhQBQ9',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        crossDomain:true,
        success:function(data){
            $.each(data, function(i,item){
                $("#results").append("<span class='result' >" + item.name + "</span></br>");
                if ( i == 3 ) return false;
            });
        },
        error:function(jqxhr,err,status){
            alert(status);
        }
    });
});
```

The 401 error coming back requires authentication - invalid API key.

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/CqrPe/

Comment: even in your page, I don't see anything in the result's panel even though if you copied the link of json file it will just print the json file

Comment: It's a 401 error. You need to be investigating your HTTP authorization: http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E401.html

Comment: Yea the previous answer still holds likely to be true, that the remote page is not handling jsonp properly.

Comment: this error message show up after I updated the call (to another file that supprts jsonp) "jQuery16209167494962457567_1312143938084 was not called" see the page here http://rawaji.com/test.html and you can see the json (manually created) file here http://www.som1.net/file.json - what is wrong ?

Comment: Here's a working example I made for another user a few days ago for proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/bhXbh/59/ If you look at your JSON file: http://www.som1.net/file.json you can see the callback is called `jQuery` which is not dynamic. Try changing that to `?`